# Combine conditions in table expression?

Tags: abap, sap-data-dictionary

I am using the `line_index` function and would like to search for two values, not only for `carrid` but also for `connid`. Is it possible? If so, in what way?

Because right now, this works:

```
lv_index = line_index( lt[ carrid = 'LH' ] ).
```

But after adding the code `[ connid = '2407' ]` like this:

```
lv_index = line_index( lt[ carrid = 'LH' ][ connid = '2407' ] ).
```

I get a syntax error:

> LT[ ] is not an internal table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All fields (conditions) just one after the other inside one bracket:

```
lv_index = line_index( lt[ carrid = 'LH'
                           connid = '2407' ] ).
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to comment about the chaining of [Table Expressions](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abentable_expressions.htm).

So the answer corresponding to the OP example is that a single Table Expression must be used (`itab[...]`) with as many components as needed, and not a chain of table expressions as was done (`itab[...][...]`).

`lt[ carrid = 'LH' ][ connid = '2407' ]` can never be valid (because `connid  = '2407'` would imply that each line of `LT` is itself an internal table but `carrid = 'LH'` is contradictory as it means that each line of `LT` is a structure).

But other syntaxes of chained table expressions can be valid, like e.g. (provided that the internal tables are defined adequately)

```
itab[ 1 ][ comp1 = 'A' ]
itab[ comp1 = 'A' ][ 1 ]
itab[ comp1 = 'A' ]-itabx[ compx = 42 ]
```

Here is an example that you can play with:

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_structure,
         connid TYPE c LENGTH 4,
       END OF ty_structure,
       ty_table TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_structure WITH EMPTY KEY,
       BEGIN OF ty_structure_2,
         carrid TYPE c LENGTH 2,
         table  TYPE ty_table,
       END OF ty_structure_2,
       ty_table_2 TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_structure_2 WITH EMPTY KEY,
       ty_table_3 TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_table_2 WITH EMPTY KEY.

DATA(lt) = VALUE ty_table_3( ( VALUE #( ( carrid = 'LH' table = VALUE #( ( connid = '2407' ) ) ) ) ) ).

DATA(structure) = lt[ 1 ][ carrid = 'LH' ]-table[ connid = '2407' ].
```

Comment: they can be chained like you figured, but not like OP `lt[ carrid = 'LH' ][ connid = '2407' ]`, this way it is like chaining structures of the same table, which makes no sense

Comment: @Suncatcher Thanks. Answer rewritten to clarify (I hope).